# Ember Data Relationships against non standard API

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want to use Ember Data but the API I am coding against does not respect all the conventions.

My problem is that the API does not return sideloaded relationships but relationships should be loaded using a REST structure: `/model/id/relationship`.

I have the following model:

```
Library = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr 'string'
  groups: DS.hasMany 'group', {async: true}
  groupsCount: DS.attr 'number'
```

The payload looks like:

```
{
  library: {
    groups_count: 44,
    name: "demo",
    id: "545262a063726d2514390100"
  }
}
```

When I attempt to load groups using `library.get('groups')` nothing happens. It should make a call to `libraries/545262a063726d2514390100/groups`

Can I change my `RESTAdapter` to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found a way that works for me:

```
LibrarySerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend
  normalize: (type, hash, prop)->
    hash.links =
      groups: "groups"
    @_super(type, hash, prop)
```

This essentially adds a `links` object to the response, making the rest adapter follow that path to retrieve the relationship.